# How to send an email on every 10 contents that are waiting for admin approval?

Tags: emails, rules

I want to notify admin only if there are 10 nodes in a queue. If 10 such nodes do exist, a single email should be triggered to admin.

How can I do this, any idea?

Comment: By using custom module I believe or create your own action and trigger.

Comment: Ok. thank you sumit. I found an another way for getting this done . We can achieve through this way also.

Comment: @SumitMadan are you sure you'd need a custom module for this? Only Rules and VBO can get the job done also (refer to my answer to understand what I mean).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. I have get all the users (uid) of particular role from the `users_role` table.

i.e :

```
$query = 'SELECT DISTINCT(ur.uid) FROM {users_roles} AS ur WHERE ur.rid IN (:rids)';
$result = db_query($query, array(':rids' => array(3,8)));
```

2. Next step, I have count nids from `workbench_moderation_node_history` table.

i.e  I have made one function like `get_train_users()` in which i have returned the above `$result` array.

```
$trainusers = get_train_users();
foreach ($trainusers as $key => $value) {
   $tresult [] = db_query ('SELECT COUNT(nid) AS con,uid FROM  {workbench_moderation_node_history} WHERE uid = :uid AND state = :state' ,array(':uid' => $value, ':state' => $state))->fetchAll();
}
```

3. Now, In last step, I am counting the count of `con`, Like if it is greater then 10, then i am sending the mail when cron runs.

That's it.

Answer (score 1):

As a variation to what's described in your own answer (using custom code), you can make this work also by using [Rules](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules) in combination with the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module, as further detailed below.

#### Step 1

Use the [Views Bulk Operations](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_bulk_operations) module to create a view of all your nodes that "*are pending, waiting for admin approval*" (as in your question), in which you add a VBO field to it. Simply include a field like `nid` for each node (no need for any other fields). Just make sure you get exactly 1 row for each node (waiting admin approva) you want to take into consideration.

#### Step 2

Create a Rules Component with a Rules Condition "***Check number of results returned by a VBO view***". And select the VBO view created in the previous step. If the number of results is 10 or more, then perform a Rules Action (in that Rules Component) to trigger your eMail for the admin.

#### Step 3

Create a Rule like so:

- Use some relevant **Rules Event** related to the creation (and possible update also?) of those nodes which are waiting admin approval.
- Don't use any **Rules Conditions** (there is no need for them in this rule).
- Perform a **Rules Action** to execute the Rules Component from Step 2.

***Done!***

PS: I'm assuming this question is about D7.